# Excel Transpose - Jagged Array

Tags: excel, vba, transpose, jagged-arrays

I need to transpose or convert a jagged array into multiple columns in excel and am having some difficulties. My data is as follows:

```
Round  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
 1     1  2  3
 2        4     5
 3     6           7
 4        8     9
```

So I need to flatten this where I go through each row, and translate each set of sequence numbers to an individual one with only one column being marked per row

```
SeqNum A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
 1     1 
 2        2 
 3           3
 4        4
 5             5
 6    6
 7                7
 8       8
 9            9
```

I've edited the numbers in the example to make it clearer. Basically I want to flatten the first table which has multiple entries per row, to the second table which only has 1 entry per row.

I have the following algorithm that I would like to implement in Excel

```
int numOfTotalElements = 0;
List<int> flattened = new List<int>();
int numRows = matrix.length;
for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
     flattened.add(matrix[i][j])
  }//end cols
}// end rows

foreach( int i in flattened){
  System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: There is a big difference between *'having some difficulties'* and *'phishing for someone to do my work for me'*. Anyone asking for code in this forum is **expected** to show original effort; not just a list of requirements. On top of everything else, your profile shows a history of abandoning your questions once you've received an answer (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). Your question was interesting; it's a shame you didn't put some effort into it.

Comment: Jeeped, no one is phishing here, I am not very adept at VBA otherwise, this is a trival problem to solve in any other language. How do you know I haven't worked on it ? Perhaps, you are the one phishing for gratitude. If you didnt want to answer the question, you didn't need to try and lecture either. Next time keep your opinions to yourself, and either answer the question or move on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this *'gimme teh codez'* request as off-topic because it is patently inadequate as an [SO](http://goo.gl/whPhMk) question and could in no way benefit any future viewer. The OP has not demonstrated even a rudimentary knowledge of the platform; has shown no original effort beyond a list of requirements and sample data. This question is worthless to [SO](http://goo.gl/whPhMk) on every level that a question is measured by.

Comment: Wow, maybe to you it doesn't have any benefit but it does to me. I am looking for a pointer here on how to do this in excel, not VBA, so don't get to excited.

Comment: I don't understand how this has been put on hold ? Because some nerd got upset that I told him to mind his business. If i knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking the question here. You can see from his first response that he was assuming and accusing me of not doing any work on the problem, and he was upset that I had "abandoned" my other questions. This Jeeped should be reprimanded for inhibiting the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if one of these gets you where you are trying to go.

**[Option 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)** [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)

```
Sub expandFlatten()
    Dim c As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vals As Variant, nuvals As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            vals = .Cells.Value2
        End With
        c = UBound(vals, 2) + 2
        .Cells(1, c).CurrentRegion.Clear
        .Cells(1, c).Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals
        With .Cells(1, c).CurrentRegion
            .Cells(1, 1) = "SeqNum"
            .Offset(1, 1).ClearContents
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Application.Max(.Parent.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion), 1) _
                .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
        End With
        With .Cells(1, c).CurrentRegion
            ReDim nuvals(1 To .Rows.Count - 1, 1 To .Columns.Count - 1)
            For i = LBound(vals, 1) + 1 To UBound(vals, 1)
                For j = LBound(vals, 2) + 1 To UBound(vals, 2)
                    If Not IsEmpty(vals(i, j)) And IsNumeric(vals(i, j)) Then
                        nuvals(vals(i, j), j - 1) = vals(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
            .Offset(1, 1).Resize(UBound(nuvals, 1), UBound(nuvals, 2)) = nuvals

        End With
        .Activate
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

**[Option 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula)** [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula)

After recreating the column header labels and a number sequence down the right side (up to `MAX(B:F)`), place this standard formula in P2,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B, MATCH($O2,B:B, 0)), "")
```

Fill both right and down.

---

[image: expandFlatten]
                    <sup>original data</sup>                                <sup>expandFlatten()</sup>                            <sup>INDEX(..., MATCH(...</sup>

---

Comment: It probably doesn't matter here, but I would suggest loading all the cell contents into a memory array (with `vals = Range("A2").Resize(5,6).Value2`) and also caching all the `UBOUND()` statements into variables.

Comment: Jeeped, I believe your solution works number 2 works. Option 1 I haven't tested, as I dont know VBA so I wouldn't be able to modify it. I will try it out though, since you put in the effort anyways. Thanks again. Now how do I mark this as answered.

Comment: John, if you are interested in tidying up your question queue, click the link I provided in my original comment on this question. Friendly advice: while acknowledging a response as the 'accepted answer' is a strictly voluntary action, it does increase your own reputation in this community and may put your future questions in a more favorable perspective from the point of view of people contemplating taking the time to respond.